# RegEx not working on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have this form Builder group for my `form` and I want to add a pattern to validate the email address but the regex i'm using is not working. This is my code.
I am new to Angular 2 and I will need some help.

Thank You

```
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    'name': new Control('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('[\\a-z\\A-Z\\s]+')
        ])),
    'gender': new Control('Male'),
    'email': new Control('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(re)
    ]))
});
```

Comment: I think you may use [`var re = '(?:[^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+(?:[.][^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+)*|".+")@(?:\\[[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}]|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,})';`](https://regex101.com/r/KyZbb0/1) (the link is only for copying the string literal for you to test against, do not copy/paste from SO comment directly).

Comment: See [the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qWXYCnZybeBHx5toq1bg?p=preview)